# SCP not updating price or adding to cart on custom theme

Tags: magento

(SCP is Simple Configurable Products extension from magentocommerce)
I use a custom printshop theme on my magento store.

Here is a screenshot of what my product page looks like with no SCP installed. http://prntscr.com/a4ubi0 It looks good but prices do not update to the simple product price.

So now when I install SCP, here is what the product detail page looks like: http://prntscr.com/a4ucby You can see SCP ruins the page layout, and the price does not update when I change options.

However it does start off from the lowest price. And If I turn my theme to default, the SCP works 100% fine.

Something must be conflicting, but honestly, im not quite sure where to start? My guess would be checking ID's from my product.phtml to the normal default, but theres so much there i dunno where to start.

Comment: You should not use SCP, it hasn't been maintained for years. That being said, there are two reputable dev companies who are maintaining forks from it. Look it up on GitHub.

Comment: Yeah I knew it hadnt been maintained, it worked fine on my old theme, however since updating to a new theme which is a lot more customized. Im unable to find the forks which are still being maintained. I will continue hunting around on google, if I find nothing will end up just paying a company to do it I guess.